# Projection operator property

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $\pi_M(a)$(projection operator) be the closest point of $M$ from the point $a$ . How one can prove if $M$ is convex set of $\mathbb R^n$ then projection operator has this property?

$$\lVert\pi_M(a)-\pi_M(b)\lVert \le \lVert a-b\lVert$$
This picture illustrates that.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the orthogonal projections of $a$ and $b$ onto the line through $\pi_M(a)$ and $\pi_M(b)$. They can't lie within the segment $\pi_M(a)\pi_M(b)$, since otherwise they would lie in $M$ (by convexity) and be closer to $a$ or $b$ than $\pi_M(a)$ or $\pi_M(b)$, respectively. Thus $\lVert\pi_M(a)-\pi_M(b)\rVert$ is at most the distance between the orthogonal projections, and that's at most the distance between $a$ and $b$.